# Delete picture from photos view, keep in albums

Tags: iphone, photos, photos.app, photo-stream

I don't have any Apple products, so sorry if this is an stupid question - I'm an assistant and have been tasked with solving this for my boss. When you open the photos app, you have two options at the bottom: "Photos" and "Albums." Is it possible to delete pictures from the "Photos" tab, but keep them in the "Albums" tab? Or even a way to hide the "Photos" view from being an option? Thanks for the help!

Comment: It's not possible,  and I don't think there is a jailbreak tweak to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible.

Think of one as the Library & the other as the Playlist, similar to iTunes.

You can have something in the Library that is not in any Album [Playlist] but you cannot have anything in an Album [Playlist] that is not already in the main Library.

Answer (score 1):

This *is* (sort of) possible in iOS 9.

- Go to albums
- Find your picture(s)
- Tap the share button in the bottom left
- Tap "hide"
- It will ask if you want to hide the picture, stating "it will be hidden from moments but still visible in albums"
- Tap "Hide Photo"

The picture will not be visible in the Photos tab but it will be visible in your albums.

To unhide the picture, go to Albums > Hidden, select your pictures, tap the Share icon and tap "Unhide"